# Navigating between same components using Back/Forward browser buttons does not work

Tags: angular2-routing

Hi I'm having trouble navigating with a browsers back/forward buttons. It only occurs when navigating between routes that share the same component via route parameters.

I have an application that lists lots of animals. Every time I navigate to example.com/animal/cat or example.com/animal/dog, a Http Get request is made to a restful Api which returns the relevant data. If I navigate to /animal/cat then to /animal/dog everything seems ok. The problem starts when I click on the browsers Back Button to go back to /animal/cat. Instead of loading the data for the cat, the URL changes but the data is still listed for the dog. I'm using router 3.0.0-beta.2 with RC4.

heres my animals details.component page:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'animal-details',
  templateUrl: 'animal-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['animal-details.component.css'],
  directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]

})
export class AnimalDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService, private router: Router) {

  }

  private subscription: Subscription;

  animal = {};

  link: string;
  table = 'animal/';
  private url = '?related=family_by_link';


  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    (param: any) => this.link = param['link']
    );

    this.dataService.getData(this.table, this.link, this.url)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {this.animal = data},
      err => { console.log('error404') }
    );
  };
  nextData(){
    this.dataService.getData(this.table, this.link, this.url)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {this.animal = data},
      err => { console.log('error404') }
    );
    window.scroll(0,0);
  };

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  };

}
```

I use the getData() method when navigating between animals on the same component. My AnimalComponentDetails html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 text-xs-center" *ngFor="let family of animal.family_by_link" (click)="nextData()">
    <a [routerLink]="['/animal', family.ani_link]">
    <img src="/images/animal/{{family.ani_link}}.png">
    <p>{{family.name}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Heres my DataService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private dataService: Http) {
  }
  urlprefix = 'http://123.123.123.123/api/v2/_table/';
  api = '&api_key=7201521drgdc71';

  getData(table, link, url): Observable<any> {
    return this.dataService.get(this.urlprefix + table + link + url +this.api);
  }
}
```

my app.routes:

```
  import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
  import { AnimalComponent } from './animal/animal.component';
  import { AnimalDetailsComponent } from './animal/animal-details/animal-details.component'

  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'animal', component: AnimalComponent },
  { path: 'animal/:link', component: AnimalDetailsComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectedTo: 'error404', component: Error404Component }
];

export const APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER = [
  provideRouter(APP_ROUTES)
];
```

And my boot:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER } from './app/app.routes'

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Chrome's Network indicates when I navigate back or forward on the same component between animal/:cat and animal/:dog via browser buttons, no new Http requests are made unless I change to a different component.

This is the last bug I'm down too. Would appreciate any help, thanks!